# Asus 1215n Volume Fn keys stopped working

Tags: netbook, fn-key

Probably I've stopped some kind of Asus utility by mistake with soluto (a tool to decide which software shold start when you boot windows) and now all my fn keys work except the volume one and once I used to get a graphical window to show me what kind of function I pressed and the level of that function e.g. brightness and now it's gone.

Any hints about what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the applications soluto disabled one at a time to identify which of them deals with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> functionality you want.

When you have found them tell soluto to allow them to start or get [another app to do it](https://superuser.com/questions/81671/what-is-the-ultimate-startup-managing-application).

Answer (score 2):

Go to [ASUS](http://usa.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=HrglRhH8D60Rmlv3) site and under download, select Windows 7, and then under Utilities select KB Filter Utility (The last one). Install and that should do the work.

Comment: I've tried it but didn't solve my problem :(